# checking json array with my value to do operation otherwise other operation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

consider i have an json array like this

```
["map14","map20","map21","map22","map23","map24","map25","map31","map32","map33","map34","map35","map36","map37","map40","map41","map42","map46","map49","map50"]
```

with this json array i need to check if my passed value exists need to do some operation or otherwise some other operation....

javascript code:

```
function pop(e,id) { 
$.getJSON( 'layoutcheck.php', { some_get_var: 1 }, function(output){
    var i=0, total = output.length;
    for ( i = 0; i < total; ++i ) {
if(isArray(output[i]==id)) {

// do soome stuff if the value exists in the database
      }
else{
// if not exists some other operation
 }
    }
});
}
</script>
```

layoutcheck.php  will fetch the information from the database and create a json array..

but the code fails to display output.. please rectify me ..

thanks

Comment: So what is the question ? Update: ok you just updated your question.

Comment: but the above code fails to display ... if modify some thing .. it will be performing either one operation ie if or else

Comment: Did you `console.log(output);` to check what it contains ?

Comment: You just need `if (output[i] === id)) {` since `isArray` is most probably undefined (unless it's some function you defined before)

Comment: thanks at last done it..

Comment: @Rishabh you are correct with your suggestion, but wrong in `isArray`'s definition. Was added in ECMA 5.1

Answer (score 0):

`isArray()` won't check if the object is in the array, but if the object is an array.

This means that `output[i]==id` (which is either `true` or `false`) is checked.
They are always *not* arrays; meaning you'll always go to the `else` part of the condition.

You can try using something like:

```
if(output.indexOf(id) != -1) {
    // do soome stuff if the value exists in the database
}
else{
    // if not exists some other operation
}
```

Instead of your `for` loop.

Comment: any idea looping through json array with my id and performing operation

Comment: In that case as @Rishabh suggested you'll need to do: `if (output[i] === id))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if `id` is in the array `output`, use Javascript's built-in `indexOf()` method:

```
if (output.indexOf(id) != -1) {
    // do soome stuff if the value exists in the database
} else {
    // if not exists some other operation
}
```

The way you wrote it, you'll do the `else` clause for every value in `output` that doesn't match `id`.